# ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Ive developed several apps on heroku before and never ran into this error:

`ActionView::Template::Error (application.css isn't precompiled):`

My latest push didn't even have a change to the `application.css` file.. Whats going on here?

Ive seen articles saying change a line in `production.rb` to:

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = true
```

But wont that slow everything down? Why is this error suddenly happening? Whats the best way to fix it?

Edit:
I should note its working in development just fine.

Comment: Did you perhaps check in `public/assets/manifest.yml` into source control? If heroku sees that it will not precompile your assets. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails3x-asset-pipeline-cedar for more information about how they work with precompiling assets. And you most definitely do not want to change your configuration, compiling assets in production is much slower.

Comment: I didnt touch it. I did the usual `git add .` then `git commit -m "message"` then `git push heroku master`. Only one file was changed and it was a rake file.

Comment: @danielevans after reading that documentation I redeployed and never saw any output saying `-----> Preparing Rails asset pipeline`, it seems from the documentation it should always at least say that whether I am precompiling or not.

Comment: if `Rakefile` changed, it is possible that the precompile action was disabled or broken by that change. I suggest that you check them locally and see if they work.

Comment: @danielevans `RakeFile` didn't change. `scheduler.rake` did. What do you mean by test locally. The app runs fine on my localhost if thats what you mean.

Comment: You can actually run `rake assets:precompile:all` in your development environment. Ensure that it does not give you an error and that it creates `public/assets/application.css`

Comment: @DanielEvans Perfect! Showed me a stupid error in my scheduler. All is well now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Run `rake assets:precompile:all` in your development environment. Ensure that it does not give you an error and that it creates `public/assets/application.css`. If it does give you an error, resolving it should resolve the problem on Heroku.

Comment: `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile` is what Heroku will run – it won't compile them for any other env.